# How to add (pointer of) an object to vector in its constructor?

Tags: c++, declaration, forward-declaration

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
struct object{
    int value;
    string name;
    object(string str, int val):name(str), value(val){
        objList.push_back(this);
    }
};

vector<object*> objList;
```

I want to add pointer of an object when creating it, but the program gives error:"Use of undeclared identifier 'objList'", I moved the declaration of objList over define of object, and it gives warning:"Use of undeclared identifier 'object'". How do I add the pointer of an object when creating it?

Comment: If you want the `objList` to be a member of the `struct object` declare it within the struct declaration scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
using namespace std;

vector<struct object*> objList;

struct object{
    int value;
    string name;
    object(string str, int val): value(val), name(str) {
        objList.push_back(this);
    }
};
```

or

```
using namespace std;

struct object;

vector<object*> objList;

struct object{
    int value;
    string name;
    object(string str, int val): value(val), name(str) {
        objList.push_back(this);
    }
};
```